# Stack Exchange Desktop Notifications

Tags: script, greasemonkey, notifier, tampermonkey

Below is a copy of http://shu8.github.io/SE_Notifications/:

#### Stack Exchange Notifications

This userscript will make HTML5 notifications popup when *something* happens on a question that you have open in a different tab. This is useful for keeping track of events without having to keep going back to see whether a new comment has been added, or an edit has been made. Inspired by [this question on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246404/260841).

#### How to use

- You need an access token. Get one [here](https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=5174&scope=write_access&redirect_uri=http://shu8.github.io/SE_Notifications)
- Install [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) (Firefox) or [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) (Chrome). These are userscript managers and allow the script to make use of `GM_*` functions, which it relies on to save your access token
- Install the script: <kbd>[Install](https://github.com/shu8/SE_Notifications/raw/master/SENotifications.user.js)</kbd> or <kbd>[View source](https://github.com/shu8/SE_Notifications/blob/master/SENotifications.user.js)</kbd>

#### What events cause a notification?

- A new comment will make a notification displaying the comment (uses the API to get the new comment, hence the access token requirement)
- A new edit will notify you an edit has been made
- A new answer will notify you it has been added
- Accepts/unnaccepts will notify you the action has taken place
- Score changes to any posts will notify you there has been a score change

#### Notes

- Thanks to everybody's efforts at Meta.SE to document the Web Sockets that Stack Exchange uses. This userscript uses these sockets to find out if there has been a new event. Go upvote them [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218343/260841)!
- Your browser needs too support Web Socket *and* HTML5 notifications for this to work
- This userscript needs an access token because it uses the API to get the 'new comment' and display it to you in the notification; without an access token, you'd probably end up making too many calls and get blocked for a day!

#### Bugs & Feature-requests

Please post any bugs or feature requests at the GitHub rep, where I will watch and try my best to add the feature/fix the bug :)

Comment: This interferes with at least some SOX features.  For example, the patch for padding content on the Fix Top Bar feature doesn't work with this enabled.