# How to use Stack Exchange WebSockets?

Tags: support, discussion, notifier

I am developing a Visual Studio Extension where I would be knowing about the activity on my posts. I found out that `wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com` is used for this purpose. Can somebody help me in explaining how to achieve the solution, i.e., how do I get to know about the activities on my posts? Also, are Stack Exchange WebSockets officially supported (like the API)?

Comment: I've used the Web Sockets in [my userscript over here](http://stackapps.com/questions/6460/stack-exchange-desktop-notifications) - you might like to check out the source :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the WebSockets are not officially supported. They are internal to Stack Exchange, use them at your own risk.

If it is at all possible to do your task with **[the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), use that.** That's what it's there for.

Some people have sussed out **some of the endpoints**.  You can see them in the answers to:
[**How do the Stack Exchange WebSockets work? What are all the options you can send to them?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218343/148310)

There was [some talk of open-sourcing Stack Exchange's custom *protocol*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168148/148310) (not the endpoints):

> Note by [Marc Gravell♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell): if people would be genuinely interested in our releasing this as open source, please let us know. It will take some effort. but isn't impossible.

But this doesn't seem to have happened.